# Finding spatial data on Enumeration Area boundaries from South Africa 2001 Census?

Tags: data, census, administrative-boundaries, south-africa

I am trying to locate spatial data for the boundaries of South African Enumeration Areas (EAs) from the 2001 Census. The links to the data from the 2001 census on the Statistics South Africa website say "object not found".

Comment: Any idea why StatsSA doesn't make this available on the web? The only source I could find was a link to a "GIS CD" that might be able to be mailed. I'm trying to turn around a quickie map and doubt international shipping can get it to me in time. It looks like the data had been posted to the openAfrica open data site, but was deleted for some reason 3 years ago: https://africaopendata.org/en/dataset/activity/cen Would love to find this online.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/160431)

Answer (score 1):

Just email StatsSA. They should be able to give you the complete Census 2011 Spatial Geography. It includes all admin boundaries down to EA and SAL. It's a huge file so you will have to get it in person or download it from their server.